# Mysql join query failure

Tags: mysql

For the tables below I need to output the rows that are not in the member_booking table from master_vehicle_inventory table.
I also need the results from master_vehicle_inventory which don't fall between the range of mb_startdate and mb_returndate.

```
master_vehicle_inventory table
mvi_id  
1          
2           
3        
4

member_booking table

   mb_id   mb_startdate   mb_returndate    mvi_id
    100      22-04-2016      30-04-2016       2
    101      23-01-2016      02-05-2016       3
```

So far I have tried this:

```
SELECT
    mb.mb_id,
    mb.mb_startdate,
    mb.mb_returndate,
    mvi.mvi_id
FROM master_vehicle_inventory AS mvi LEFT JOIN LEFT
    JOIN member_booking AS mb ON mvi.mvi_id = mb.mvi_id
WHERE CURDATE() NOT BETWEEN mb.mb_startdate
      AND mb.mb_returndate
      AND mvi.mvi_id NOT IN (SELECT mvi.mvi_id
                             FROM member_booking)
```

But it doesn't give the results want.

Comment: Sorry...the question is not well formatted....

Comment: Hi there, I edited the body to start with the question and not with a table. I also tried to understand your first question and redraft it, so it is more understandable. Please correct it if you think it's not what you want.
For future questions please also indented your mysql query, so it's easier to read. To improve your chance of getting an correct answer you could give a minimal result to better visualize your need. 
Also try to include the error message, if there is one. It will help people to better help you! Good luck!

Comment: Thansk cb0. Kinda new here so do not have idea abt the formating of while asking question...i will keep in mind next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return rows from `master_vehicle_inventory` which do not have a "matching" row in `member_booking` table, we can use an anti-join pattern.

Assuming \mb_startdate` and `mb_enddate` are defined as datatype DATE.

Something like this:

```
SELECT mvi.mvi_id
  FROM master_vehicle_inventory mvi
  LEFT
  JOIN member_booking mb
    ON mb.mvi_id       =  mvi.mvi_id
   AND mb.mb_startdate <= DATE(NOW())
   AND mb.mb_enddate   >  DATE(NOW())
 WHERE mb.mvi_id IS NULL
```

(The specification for a "matching" row is a bit vague.)

Given DATE(NOW()) returns  '2016-04-25' we expect that query to return rows

```
mvi_id
------
1
4
```

(We are suspicious that the datatype of the columns may not be DATE because the values shown in the example data are *not* in the YYYY-MM-DD format we expect returned for a DATE expression.)